# How to move marker in google map for a vechicle tracking application

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my application I want to track the vehicles,am getting multiple latitude and longitude from JSON I plotted the latlong in the google map,when the latlong changes in JSON the marker has to move.but here it moves by creating an new marker the previous marker is still exist.how can I remove the marker in the previous location

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) {
if (mMap == null) { 
            mMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mapView)).getMap(); 
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 

            Location myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation(); 
            if (mMap != null) {  
                //mMap.clear();

                // setUpMap(); 
                mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() { 

                    @Override 
                    public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) { 

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                        final LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder(); 
                     mMap.clear();
                        if (marker != null) {
                             marker.remove();
                         }
                        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.size(); i++) { 
                            final LatLng position = new LatLng(Double 
                                    .parseDouble(arraylist1.get(i).get("Latitude")), 
                                    Double.parseDouble(arraylist1.get(i).get( 
                                            "Longitude"))); 
                            String ime1 = arraylist1.get(i).get("IME");

                            final MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions() 
                            .position(position); 
                            //mMap.addMarker(options); 
                            //mMap.addMarker(options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.buspng)).title(ime1));

                              marker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.buspng)).title(ime1));

                            //options.title(ime1);
                            builder.include(position); 

                        } 
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0 
                                .getLongitude()); 
                        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 

                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 
                        // mMap.setOnMapClickListener(null); 
                        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(null); 

                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(9)); 
                    } 
                }); 

            } 
        } 
    } 

    /*  protected void retrieveAndAddCities() throws IOException { 
        HttpURLConnection conn = null; 
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder(); 
        try { 

            URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL); 
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()); 

            int read; 
            char[] buff = new char[1024]; 
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) { 
                json.append(buff, 0, read); 
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e); 
            throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e); 
        } finally { 
            if (conn != null) { 
                conn.disconnect(); 
            } 
        } 
        new DownloadJSON().execute(); 

    } */

    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
        String result=""; 
        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            super.onPreExecute(); 
        }

        @Override 
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
            try { 
                arraylist1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser(); 
                String result = ""; 

                json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(SERVICE_URL); 

                try { 
                    //arraylist1.clear(); 

                    jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("SingleIMEs"); 
                    Log.d("Haaaaaaaaaaaa", "" + json); 

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) { 
                        Log.d("H11111111111111111111111111", 
                                "" + jsonarray.length()); 
                        map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                        json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i); 

                        // pubname = json.getString("PubName"); 
                        latitude = json.getDouble("Latitude"); 
                        longitude = json.getDouble("Longitude"); 
                        ime = json.getString("IME");
                        //  map.put("PubName", json.getString("PubName")); 
                        //map.put("PubID", json.getString("PubID")); 
                        map.put("Latitude", json.getString("Latitude")); 
                        Log.e("CHECKLAT",""+json.getString("Latitude") );
                        map.put("Longitude", json.getString("Longitude")); 
                        Log.e("CHECKLONG",""+json.getString("Longitude") );

                        map.put("IME", json.getString("IME"));
                        arraylist1.add(map); 
                    } 

                } catch (JSONException e) { 
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString()); 
                    result="Error"; 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            }catch(Exception e){ 
                result="Error"; 
            } 

            return null; 
        } 

        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) { 

            // mProgressDialog.dismiss(); 

        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onResume() { 
        super.onResume(); 
        mMapView.onResume(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onPause() { 
        super.onPause(); 
        mMapView.onPause(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onDestroy() { 
        mMapView.onDestroy(); 
    super.onDestroy(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   /* Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onLocationUpdated!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("onLocationUpdated!!!","");
        new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
        setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView);*/

    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 


}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if (marker != null) {
>     marker.remove();
> }
> ```

Do you actually have a function to remove the marker here? If not, you have to remove the marker from the map and set it to `null` in order to remove it.

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

Source: [marker API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#remove)